# Malloc warning in C

Tags: c, malloc, warnings

> Controller* ctrl = (Controller*)malloc(sizeof(Controller));

- incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]
- implicit declaration of function 'malloc' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  What I'm doing wrong with this malloc?

Comment: did you include the appropriate header? (i.e. `malloc.h`)

Comment: You need to #include <stdlib.h>

Comment: BTW: you aren't using malloc to allocate objects, are you?

Comment: Don't cast malloc return value in C, only in C++.

Comment: [Read this](http://c-faq.com/) before you get yourself into further trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try do add this at the beginning of your file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: correct, I edited my answer.